# Is it possible to compare aggregate column to normal column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to compare an aggregate column to a normal column, but can't figure out how. As you can't use aggregates in where clause, but also can't use normal column in having clause.

```
select table1.id, (table1.total1 - sum(table2.total2*table2.quantity)) as finalTotal 
from table1, table2
where table1.id=table2.fid
group by table1.id
having table1.total1 > sum(table2.total2*table2.quantity)
```

The problem is on the having line as you can use (table1.total1) there.

Comment: Wow, this is a really strange query, not only due to refusal of using modern JOIN. I think you should please better show sample input and expected outcome as tables and let people here think about a correct query.

Comment: It may not be a valid SQL query even in the select-list, because you're doing arithmetic between a non-aggregated column `table1.total1` and the aggregated `sum()` expression. So which row in the group should be used for that subtraction arithmetic? Unless `id` is the primary key (which it might be, but you haven't defined the table in this post), the query makes no sense.

Comment: While I don't understand what this query would achieve, you can get a result by including the table1.total1 in both the SELECT, and the GROUP BY parts.

Comment: Please  add sample data and desired results.